# Query result from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two tables : galleries and shared galleries.

**Structure of galleries:** (for storing images of individual students. One student contains multiple images)

```
id, student_id, classroom_id, image
```

**Structure of shared_galleries:** (for storing images which are common to all students in a classroom. One classroom contains many images):

```
id,classroom_id,image
```

Other than these two tables I have students table and classrooms table. Students table store the classroom_id.

I need to get a query so that I can display the images stored in 'galleries' for a student and those stored in shared gallery of the classroom in which that student belongs in a single page. How can I achieve this ? Something like this returns duplicated results :

```
select galleries.id as gid, 
       shared_galleries.id as sid,
       galleries.student_id, galleries.classroom_id 
from galleries 
     inner join shared_galleries on galleries.classroom_id=shared_galleries.classroom_id 
where galleries.student_id=31 and galleries.classroom_id=28
```

Comment: you need more tables for this; I'm assuming you have also `student`, `classroom` and `classrooms_students` ?

Comment: I have students table and classroom table too

Comment: and no link between students and classrooms ?

Comment: Classroom id of student is stored in students table

Comment: you should include that in the question

Comment: Sorry for that. It is now edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You will need to join the student to the `shared_galleries` along the relations to get the right results

```
SELECT 
    g.image AS image,
    0 AS is_shared
WHERE 
    g.student_id = :student_id
FROM
    galleries AS g
UNION
SELECT
    sg.image AS image,
    1 AS is_shared
FROM 
    shared_galleries AS sg
    LEFT JOIN classrooms AS c ON c.id = sg.classroom_id
    LEFT JOIN students AS s ON s.classroom_id = c.id
WHERE 
    s.id = :student_id
```

This should give you all the images for a student  with `:student_id`,
I've also added the `is_shared` column in case you need to know the origin of the image

Comment: I cannot use union since it won't support pagination in laravel. I am facing the issue pointed here :https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21958

Comment: there are solutions in that same issue ;)

Comment: Didn't worked for me though :(. If I was able to join them in any ways, I could have used the default pagination

Comment: How about creating a view based on this query then using the view?

Comment: this didn't worked?
https://github.com/krossroad/laravel-unionpaginator

Comment: I did this by creating a view with 2 tabs for showing both type of images so that I can use laravel's default pagination.  And then I changed the pagination to ajax pagination.

Comment: if you want 2 separate paginations for the 2 different galleries than you can't use one sql query

Answer (score -1):

Since your images are stored on a per-record basis (in both galleries and shared galleries, using a JOIN is not needed.  Use a UNION instead:

```
SELECT 
    galleries.id AS ID, 
    galleries.student_ID AS StudentID, 
    galleries.classroom_id as ClassroomID, 
    galleries.image as Image 
WHERE 
    galleries.student_id = 31
UNION
SELECT
    shared_galleries.id AS ID, 
    NULL AS StudentID, 
    shared_galleries.classroom_id as ClassroomID, 
    shared_galleries.image as Image 
WHERE 
    shared_galleries.classroom_ID = 31
```

This will produce a list of records, with each record containing one image (since the number of images per student and the number if images per classroom is never consistent)

If you want do a little extra and ensure that your classroom images are always linked to the correct student, then declare a variable at the beginning to set the student_id value, and then use it in the second SELECT statement.

Comment: almost right, but you will need to join the students table to the second query in the union to ensure that the student_id is correct

Comment: @zedling I disagree.  Since the classroom images are never linked to a student, having the student_id appear in the result set would be misleading and inaccurate.  The data would be more correct for the student_id to be NULL for images coming from the shared gallery.

Comment: that might be true, I'll get back on it later; also you forgot the `FROM` parts from the query

Comment: @Tyler I am using laravel framework. I already tried union and got the result but in laravel, union doesn't work with pagination. That is why I am trying to join tables

Comment: @bincymathew If you need a Laravel solution, why doesn't the question mention anything about it?

Comment: Sorry for that. Added a tag.